# PayPal Android SDK to be discontinued?

Tags: paypal

I understand that PayPal had recently deprecated its developer site from x.com and launched the new one at developer.paypal.com.
However, on the new site I can't find any reference to the Android SDK (or MLP for Android), nor on Github repositories (https://github.com/paypal).

Does anyone know what's the future of the Android SDK?

Comment: The Android SDK has been moved to github: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything has not been moved over to the new site yet.  Some of the stuff is being moved over in different phases.  The Android SDK will eventually be moved over.

Comment: Is there any public roadmap for these phases? Or at least a timeframe for an update of the Android library. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have an ETA at this time.  You should still be find the MPL on the x.com site until it's moved over.  https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-sdk-index

Answer (score 1):

use rest api and wait for new paypall android sdk

Comment: Not really a helpful answer, but thanks anyway.